# Writing attributed strings line-by-line to an RTF file

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsattributedstring, rtf

I'm trying to write a series of attributed strings to an RTF file, line-by-line at various points in my application sit is running (you can think of this as log data, only with attributes). The file is created just fine and it would appear that all the data is being written to the file, but when I open the RTF file only the first line written to the file appears. I suspect that there's something written to the file in the first write that essentially end the RTF file, but I'm not quite sure what that is.

```
- (void) writeLineWithSizeAndStyle: (NSString *) line : (CGFloat)fontSize : (NSFontTraitMask) traits {
    NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:line];
    NSFileHandle              *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:filePath];
    NSFontManager             *fm = [NSFontManager sharedFontManager];
    NSRange                   range = [line rangeOfString:line];
    NSFont                    *font = [NSFont systemFontOfSize:fontSize];

    font = [fm convertFont:font toHaveTrait:traits];
    [attrString addAttribute: NSFontAttributeName value:font range:range];
    NSData *rtfData = [attrString RTFFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length) documentAttributes:@{}];

    // Go the the end of the file, write the data, and close the file
    [fileHandle seekToEndOfFile];
    [fileHandle writeData: rtfData];
    [fileHandle closeFile];
}
```

Is there something I need to to in converting each attributed string to NSData that effectively tells RFT not to terminate the file upon writing?

Thanks!

Update:
Here's the code for solution 2 I proposed in the comments section. This operates on an instance variable in the class object (playByPlay) that simply appends each new line onto the entire "log". This works great, but again is only really a solution for sufficiently small files.

```
- (void) writeLineWithSizeAndStyle: (NSString *) line : (CGFloat)fontSize : (NSFontTraitMask) traits {
    NSFileHandle    *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:filePath];
    NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:line];
    NSRange range = [line rangeOfString:line];
    NSFontManager   *fm = [NSFontManager sharedFontManager];
    NSFont  *font = [NSFont systemFontOfSize:fontSize];
    font = [fm convertFont:font toHaveTrait:traits];

    [attrString addAttribute: NSFontAttributeName value:font range:range];

    [playByPlayText appendAttributedString:attrString];
    NSData *rtfData = [playByPlayText RTFFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, playByPlayText.length) documentAttributes:@{}];

    [fileHandle writeData: rtfData];
    [fileHandle closeFile];
}
```

Comment: Did you try to compare the result (from a whole rtf file created) and a line by line created rtf using the same initial string?

Comment: What does your caller code look like? This code would only write one line.

Comment: After digging into the RTF code generated by the above, I discovered that each NSData object produced by RTFFromRange is, itself, a fully formed RTF file, which begins and ends with {} pairs. One solution would be to strip and reinsert these brackets as necessary. Another is to maintain a separate NSMutableAttributedString that appends each new string and writes out the entire file each time. This is acceptable for the ~20K RTF files I'm working with, but would not be a particularly efficient solution for very, very large files.

Comment: Yes, this method will only write one line, but does always seek to the end of the file. The caller is spread out through out the code, sort of like NSLog, to record various events as they happen. Prior to using attributed strings I was simply writing NSStrings to .txt files and it worked fine, but I of course wanted to get a little more ambitions and use attributed strings and .rtf files.